# Laravel messenger - Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\Guard::login() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, null given

Tags: php, laravel, github, messenger

I am building a social networking site, and need a messaging system so I am using [this](https://github.com/cmgmyr/laravel-messenger), as it looks pretty good.

I have set up Laravel and I am about half way through my project. I have added in laravel-messenger but as soon as I run it I get the following error:

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\Guard::login() must implement
>   interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, null given.

I have Googled and researched but I haven't found a clear solution, I need help!

Answer (score 1):

Your User model should be like this (should implement these and use proper traits)

```
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\Authorizable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract,
                                AuthorizableContract,
                                CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword;
    //enter code here
}
```

Comment: Hi Abdul, Thank you for getting back to me, my user model does have the appropriate libraries installed. https://github.com/shep1990/messenger This is my testing environment with Messenger installed. The same error is happening here.